# How can I add new values into the next row in Excel from Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I'm working with color feature extraction and I have 27 color types. I have created the GUI to extract color features from an image and store those values in Excel. I have 2 rows and 27 columns. The first row is a header (title), the second row is the value of the header, but whenever I run the GUI with a new image it will always overwrite the values from C4 cells to AC4.

I want to make it that whenever I run the GUI to browse images and extract colour features, it will store the result in Excel and  fill in the next row (for  example C5 to AC5, run GUI again fill to C6 to AC6, run GUI again fill to C7 to AC7 etc).

I have no idea how to do that.

My Excel data looks like this:

[image: data]

My GUI looks like this:
[image: GUI]

Here is my cross-post from [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/505873-how-can-i-add-new-value-into-next-row-in-excel?s_tid=prof_contriblnk)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask], and include what you have done so far and why you are failing to accomplish your task.

Comment: hi..just click the link in matlab and it will show you everything i've done

Comment: I reformatted your question for posterity before I closed it relating to several duplicates. As an English language point, please note that ".." is not a used punctuation mark, especially when it's used in place of any spacing between sentences - ", " (comma/space) is much easier to read.